# How to emit an Observable and then throttle the subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In RxJS, filters such as `auditTime` and `throttleTime` emit an Observable (in different ways) after a certain duration has passed. I need to emit an Observable and *then* wait for a period of time before emitting the next value.

In my case I am working in Angular. For example, this code:

```
this.fooService$.pipe(throttleTime(10000)).subscribe(() => this.doSomething());
```

will not accomplish what I need because the emission happens at the end of the duration. I need the opposite: the emission happens and then a delay. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The `leading` and `trailing` options might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.3/spec/operators/throttleTime-spec.ts#L143-L155

Comment: try ``throttle()``

Comment: @cartant You're suggestion is perfect. If you write it as answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: @ebakunin If you were able to use the suggestion to solve your problem, maybe you could write a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? I don't have time to write one up ATM.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the classic timeout-function?

```
this.fooService$.subscribe( () =>
    setTimeout(() => { this.doSomething(); }, 3000)
);
```

EDIT:

Referring to your comment, do the following on your emitting side (just an example):

```
// RxJS v6+
import { timer, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

// timer starts with a delay of 1000 ms and then emits every 2000 ms
const source = timer(1000, 2000);
const emitter: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(-1);

const subscribe = source.subscribe( value => this.emitter.next(value));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for the same reason `delay` fails: the action will happen after 3 seconds, as opposed to happening and then waiting 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and do operation in `tap()`

```
this.fooService$.pipe(
tap(() => this.doSomething()),
switchMap(()=>timer(10000))
)
.subscribe();
```